# How do you use "ride" here?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

Imagine you get a BMW, and then everyone tells you:"Hey, you're gonna be so popular, you'll be driving all kinds of girls in your car", that makes sense.

And now imagine you bought a horse, and you can't use the word "ride" in there, saying:"I'll be riding all kinds of girls on my horse", because that doesn't make sense. So can you only say:"I'll be giving rides to all kinds of girls on my horse", or is there another way of saying that?

Also what about strollers? Would you also just say:"I'll be giving rides to all kinds of babies in my stroller?".

Sorry for the ridiculous question. It's just that in Russian there's a word "катать", for all of the above , I'm just trying to understand how to say it in English .

Comment: If that horse is as much of a pussy magnet as that BMW is (going by the statement of your own example), he might be riding girls on top of the horse, as well as inside the BMW.

Comment: "...you'll be driving all kinds of girls in your car," isn't all that right, either. Think again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"riding all kinds of girls" means, to almost everybody, "having sex with all kinds of girls".

To say that you're "driving all kinds of girls" technically doesn't make sense, either, because the girls are not driveable - they're not cars.

However, "drive" has crossed over into a different, more colloquial meaning, which means "to drive someone else to their destination".  The word "ride" has not undergone this transition.

Consider "Can you drive my mum to the airport please?" to "Can you ride my mum to the airport please?".  Here, the connotation (in the latter case) is not sexual, but it conjures up an image of someone putting a saddle on the speaker's mum, jumping on, and saying "Giddyup, Barbara!".

In a seperate transition, the word "ride" has also come to mean "have sex with".

So, in the example of "I'll be riding all kinds of girls on my horse", ride (unlike 'drive') has not crossed over to mean "give a ride to", and so we can't take that meaning.  Instead, we fall back onto a different alternative meaning, of "have sex with".

Regarding strollers, I think you **could** say "I'll be giving rides to all kinds of babies in my stroller", although obviously you should always gain permission from their parents.

EDIT as @Kris pointed out in the comments, I didn't answer one of the (several) questions in the Question.

In answer to

"So can you only say:*"I'll be giving rides to all kinds of girls on my horse"*, or is there another way of saying that?"

: it's a weird thing to say, so it's a bit tricky to decide what the best way to rephrase it is.  I would probably say *"I'll be giving rides to all **sorts** of girls on my horse."*.  I think that's the most idiomatic way to say it.

Comment: "To say that you're "driving all kinds of girls" technically doesn't make sense, either, because the girls are not driveable - they're not cars." True, but I think the sentence simply omits "around". "Driving girls around" is correct, I'm not sure if the omission of "around" is accepted.

Comment: Good point - I think you should work that up into an answer.

Comment: Other than that minor mention, my answer would be the same as yours. OP's focus was on the horse/ride example, not the BMW/drive which was only provided as a similar phrase. I'd much rather +1 yours than add the same answer again :)

Comment: So "drive girls" is wrong, but "drive girls around" is correct?

Comment: So what is the answer, btw?

Comment: @Pavel: "Driving girls around" is definitely correct. "Driving girls" by itself is not correct, but I am not sure whether it is considered correct to simply omit the "around". If you want to be sure, use "around". Another case: "Drive me to school" is correct, but I think this only applies because "to school" replaces "around". "Drive me" can be considered a concise command (omitting "to school" as it is already clear from context). But if your statement stands on its own without any established context, I would use "drive girls around".

Comment: @MaxWilliams, what does exchanging the word "kinds" for "sorts" have to do with the question?

Comment: @vpn I feel like it's slightly more natural, ie more likely to be said.  This may just be my opinion.  In terms of what it has to do with the question, it's a response to this specific bit of the question: *So can you only say:"I'll be giving rides to all kinds of girls on my horse", or is there another way of saying that?*